# Variables in post title

Tags: filters, title

How can I make my post title dynamic?

Let's say I'm trying to make a post with this title:

Today is [day]/[month]/[year]

[day] should be parsed into a php code that will retrieve the current day, and the same idea for [month] and [year]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `the_title` filter to hook into the title content and work with that.

```
add_filter( 'the_title', function( $title ) {
    // Manipulate the $title as you want and then return that.
    // You can add test conditions such as 'is_main_query' 
    // (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_main_query)

    return $title;
} );
```

Comment: I tried it and it worked except for the <title> tag, probably because I'm using a plugin that changes titles.

Comment: Could you show us the final code you are using please :)